# RF Communication between 2 Pis

Tags: wireless, communication, xbee, radio

I am making a quad-copter for raspberry pi. I have the physics engine build, but I need a way to control the quad-copter. So I basically need to send about 20 unsigned Integers from one pi to the other pi wirelessly, about 20 times a second. I plan on using RF 433 but there is almost no documentation on this online (other than 433 utils). Is RF 433 fast enough to send that much data a second? What is the XBEE module? Would that work better than 433 communication? Is the ZigBee the same thing? I'm kinda new to communication. I would prefer that it can send data at ATLEAST 50 meters, any more would be highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Those 433Mhz modules are rather not suited for tasks like that. You would need 2 pairs, implement your own protocol for missed packets and so on. 
You might consider nRF24l01 as way more suited solution. Specially those with external antennas